# Exactness and Products of Categories

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

A functor is left exact (resp. right exact) if it preserves finite limits (resp. finite colimits). Let $\mathcal \otimes \colon \mathcal A \times \mathcal B \longrightarrow \mathcal C$ be a bifunctor. Is there a connection between left (or right) exactness of $A \otimes -$ and $- \otimes B$ for all objects $A \in \mathcal A$ and $B \in \mathcal B$, and left (or right) exactness of $\otimes$ as a bifunctor?

For example if $k$ is a commutative ring, is $- \otimes_k -$ exact if and only if $M \otimes_k -$ and $-\otimes_k M$ exact for any $k$-module $M$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Preserving colimits in each variable separately does not imply preserving colimits jointly. Indeed, let $M = k \oplus k$. Then $M \otimes_k M$ is 4-dimensional, but $k \otimes_k k \oplus k \otimes_k k$ is 2-dimensional, so ${-} \otimes_k {-}$ does not preserve binary coproducts.

The converse is not true either. For example, ${-} \oplus {-}$ preserves colimits jointly but not in each variable: $M \oplus k$ is 3-dimensional, but $(k \oplus k) \oplus (k \oplus k)$ is 4-dimensional.

Answer (score 2):

There is a connection for certain coequalizers: A bifunctor preserves *[reflexive coequalizers](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/reflexive+coequalizer)* when it does so in each variable. This is a very nice and useful exercise. A reference is Corollary A.1.2.12 in P. T. Johnstone, *Sketches of an Elephant: A Topos Theory Compendium. Volume 1*.